# Google api 3 returning nothing when WEB APi is published

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have made a simple ASP.NET Web API that gets events from a shared google calendar, and serves them to me in json. When i fire it up from localhost i get 104 events returned: [image: from localhost] but when I've published it to my IIS server, the array contains no elements. I can't debug on it, but i get an empty array presented: [image: published]

I have made an app on https://console.developers.google.com/ and added both localhost and http://domainname.dk/oauthcallback to it.

My code:

```
public void GetFixedEvents()
        {
            const string calendarId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com";

            try
            {
                var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = clientId,
                        ClientSecret = clientSecret,

                    },
                    new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None).Result;
                var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "CalendarTest",
                });
                var queryStart = DateTime.Now;
                var queryEnd = queryStart.AddYears(1);

                var query = service.Events.List(calendarId);
                query.TimeMin = queryStart;
                query.TimeMax = queryEnd;
                query.SingleEvents = true;

                var events = query.Execute().Items;

                foreach (var item in events)
                {
                    var tempEvent = new PubEvent
                    {
                        Title = item.Summary,
                        Description = item.Description ?? "None",
                        Start = item.Start.DateTime,
                        End = item.End.DateTime,
                        EventType = item.Summary.Contains("Ladies") ? EventType.LadiesNight : EventType.StudentNight
                    };
                    _pubEvents.Add(tempEvent);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception encountered: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help? Is it a problem with redirect uri? I have tried adding all the ones I can possibly think of. Is there any way to log the call to the google api?

Comment: I've added a new PubEvent and added the errormessage in the catch block.
It says "One or more errors occured" and the stacktrace:  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at GoogleCalTestApi.Controllers.EventsController.GetMusicEvents() in c:\Users\chbj\Google Drev\Visual Studio\GoogleCalTestApi\GoogleCalTestApi\Controllers\EventsController.cs:line 79"

Comment: check this link on how to debug in iis, may be you'll get a better hint of the error: http://codetunnel.io/how-to-debug-your-aspnet-projects-running-under-iis/

Comment: Got an inner stack trace: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied\r\n at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext() in c:\\code\\google.com\\google-api-dotnet-client\\default\\Tools\\Google.Apis.Release\\bin\\Debug\\test\\default\\Src\\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\\OAuth2\\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 59

I tried changing the identity on app pool on server to Administrator

Comment: But no luck. The erquest just dragged on in an endless loop

Comment: I have the same issue. But in a different way. I am trying to upload on Youtube and eating error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess". I have changed IIS App pool identity to "Local System" and it goes in endless loop. Note that only .NET 4.5.2 has this problem. On 4.5 it worked good.